# Ballerina V 1.0 - Keep DB connection in a separate file

Tags: ballerina

In my ballerina project I have done DB connection creation and the implementation of services in the same .bal file.

```
import ballerina/config;
import ballerina/http;
import ballerina/io;
import ballerina/jsonutils;
import ballerinax/java.jdbc;

jdbc:Client studentMgtDB = new ({
    url: "jdbc:mysql://" + config:getAsString("student.jdbc.dbHost") + ":" +      config:getAsString("student.jdbc.dbPort") + "/" + config:getAsString("student.jdbc.db"),
    username: config:getAsString("student.jdbc.username"),
    password: config:getAsString("student.jdbc.password"),
    poolOptions: {maximumPoolSize: 5},
    dbOptions: {useSSL: false}
});

type Student record {
    int std_id;
    string name;
    int age;
    string address;
};

listener http:Listener studentMgtServiceListener = new (9090);

@http:ServiceConfig {
    basePath: "/students"
}

service studentMgtService on studentMgtServiceListener {

    @http:ResourceConfig {
        methods: ["GET"],
        path: "/"
    }
    resource function getStudent(http:Caller caller, http:Request req) {
        var selectStudents = studentMgtDB->select("SELECT * FROM student", Student);
        http:Response response = new;
        if (selectStudents is table<Student>) {
            response.statusCode = 200;
        } else {
            response.statusCode = 500;
        }
        checkpanic caller->respond(response);
    }
}
```

I want to move only the DB connection part into a separate file as it's better for the maintenance. So what's the best way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to manage your code in multiple bal files, you need to structure your code with the Ballerina project. Please refer to [this guide](https://v1-0.ballerina.io/learn/how-to-structure-ballerina-code/) for more information.

```
// Create a new project with the name 'student_mgt_proj'
$ ballerina new studentmgt_proj

$ cd student_mgt_proj

// Create a new module named 'studentmgt'
$ ballerina add studentmgt
```

Now add all your bal files to the `src/studentmgt` directory.

```
// Build the executable service jar
$ ballerina build studentmgt

// You can also use java -jar studentmgt.jar, if you are using Java 8
$ ballerina run studentmgt.jar
```

Comment: Thanks for this. I was also trying this. Now I have 2 .bal files as dbConn.bal and student.bal in studentmgt module. In dbConn.bal I have created a function which returns jdbc:Client. And when I'm invoking that method in student.bal, there's a compilation error appeared in dbConn.bal as "undocumented return parameter". What's the mistake I have done here?

Comment: Raised this issue as another question in: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58300618/ballerina-v-1-0-error-in-calling-function-with-jdbcclient-return-type-undoc.