# Ballerina V 1.0 - Error in Calling function with jdbc:Client return type - undocumented return parameter

Tags: ballerina

I need to call a function in test.bal. Function is written in function.bal file in the same module. Return type of the function is **jdbc:Client**.

function.bal :

```
import ballerinax/java.jdbc;

public function createDbConn() returns jdbc:Client{
    jdbc:Client testDbConn = new({
    url: "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/testDB",
    username: "testUsername",
    password: "testPassword",
    poolOptions: {maximumPoolSize: 5},
    dbOptions: {useSSL: false}
    });
return testDbConn;
}
```

Before invoking this method in test.bal, there's no compilation error.
Then I'm trying to invoke the function in test.bal as below

```
jdbc:Client testDbConn = createDbConn();

...//more code in here
var selectFromDb = testDbConn->select("SELECT * FROM test", testData);
```

After method invoking, this gives a compile error as follows in function.bal

> undocumented return parameter

What's the reason for this error? Can't I use jdbc:Client as the return type?

**PS:** This is a warning, not a compile error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
undocumented return parameter
```

should be a warning, this is when you have incomplete function documentation.

But mere invocation of the function should not produce this kind of documentation warning.

Can you try adding method return documentation to that method.

```
# + return - This is the description of the return value of
#            the `doThatOnObject` function.
```

See Ballerina doc comment examples [here](https://v1-0.ballerina.io/learn/by-example/documentation.html).

If the error still persists please report a bug at https://github.com/ballerina-platform/ballerina-lang/issues

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Yeah It's a warning not an error. When gave the correct description only this build successfully.